# Remove controller name from url for my custom module in Magento

Tags: php, magento, url-rewriting

I have created my own module. In that, I used `IndexController`. So the URL for me looks like `http://192.168.1.25/upload/index.php/capsync/index/api`.

I want to shorten the URL like `http://192.168.1.25/upload/index.php/capsync/api`.

I want to remove controller name. I tried in the `config.xml` file, but it shows a 404 error. I don't know how to fix this. Any ideas?

Comment: Fixed formatting errors.

Answer (score 2):

Try Magento rewrite functionality..
Open config.xml and add below code. It will make URL  http://192.168.1.25/module/index/index/id/5 --> http://192.168.1.25/module/id/5 like this. Change Rule according to your need.

```
<global>
<rewrite>
<fancy_url>
        <from><![CDATA[/module\/(.*)/]]></from>
        <to><![CDATA[module/index/index/id/$1/]]></to>
            <complete>1</complete>
</fancy_url>
</rewrite>
 ...
```

Comment: <global>
<rewrite>
<capsync_url>
        <from><![CDATA[/capsync/api\/(.*)/]]></from>
        <to><![CDATA[capsync/index/api/$1/]]></to>
            <complete>1</complete>
</capsync_url>
</rewrite> This is what i tried. but shows 404 error. Even after cleared cache

Comment: Please use <fancy_url> instead of <capsync_url>. If you got 404 error see the url and make changes in code according to your url to meet your goals. Code work fine, but you need to optimize according to your need. And this code should be like his -->> <from><![CDATA[/capsync\/(.*)/]]></from>

Comment: Good to know it works for you. Mark as correct. If any other will come to find the similar answer then it will be easy for them to understand that answer is correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

The most common solution for this is to divide your endpoint info different controller-files.  In your example, you could change name from `IndexController.php` to `ApiController.php` and the method name from `ApiAction()` to `IndexAction()`.

Comment: Even when i tried, that shows 404 error. Any other solution pls.

Comment: Hm, I think that perhaps you need to have an IndexController, even if it contains nothing or an empty IndexAction - but can't remember the specifics. Aslo you need to make sure you clear all caches you can find before this would show any change.

Comment: For each and every test, i used to clear cache and reindex data. but i didn't get cleared with that issue

Answer (score 0):

The code which works for me is as follows.

```
<global>
<rewrite>
<fancy_url> 
<from><![CDATA[/capsync\/(.*)/]]></from>
<to><![CDATA[/capsync/index/$1/]]></to>
<complete>1</complete>
</fancy_url>
</rewrite>
```